# After setting the windows 10 gpo "DenyUnspecified" and "DenyRemovableDevice", and configure AllowDeviceIDs device is visible but cannot be removed

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-registry, whitelist

I need to allow only specific usb media on my windows 10 Host (21h1).

The gpo configuration:

GPO_LocalMachineRegistryKeySet        `"Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions"`
"DenyUnspecified" `"DWORD:1" GPO_LocalMachineRegistryKeySet`
"Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions" `"DenyRemovableMedia`
"DWORD:1"

At first step the usb device are not visible.
I add the device in the whitelist

GPO_LocalMachineRegistryKeySet `"Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions\AllowDeviceIDs"`
"*" `
"DELETEALLVALUES"

GPO_LocalMachineRegistryKeySet `"Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions\AllowDeviceIDs"`
"1" `
"SZ:USBSTOR\GenDisk"

GPO_LocalMachineRegistryKeySet `"Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions\AllowDeviceIDs"`
"2" `
"SZ:STORAGE\VOLUME"

gpupdate.exe /force

Then I plug my usb key. The usb key is visible and mounted.
But if I remove the usb key entries from the white list and unplug/plug the usb key again, the key is still visible

Thanks